# Make a pc on lan accessible from outside network

Tags: networking, remote-access

I have a broadband service but I don't have a static IP from my ISP. I wan't to remote-access my PC from outside. If a had a static IP of my router, then I would have connected to the PC.

Is there way or any application that I can run on PC so that I can connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

use service like dydns or noip, hope that help :)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS